# Xamarin Forms overlaps systems title - how to hide FitsSystemWindows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Forms application. In the top section app overlaps with the android system topbar  (No the application bar) I am using my own custom nav bar not using inbuild.

Please suggest how to set the Android.Views.View.FitsSystemWindows property in Xamarin Forms

Comment: By custom nav bar you mean something developed in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Yes developed in xamarin forms